# Cartesian product of vectors spaces is finite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

> Suppose $V_1, \dots, V_m$ are vector spaces such that $V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m$ is finite-dimensional.  Prove that $V_j$ is finite-dimensional for each $j=1,\dots, m$.

I have written up a proof, but it just doesn't quite sound like the kinds of proofs I see in my book. Here's what I've got:

$0 \times \cdots \times 0 \times V_j \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0$ is clearly a subspace of $V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m$ (I could prove this, but I think it's pretty obvious).  Using a previous theorem, we know that if a vector space is finite-dimensional then all of its subspaces are finite-dimensional.  This implies that $0 \times \cdots \times 0 \times V_j \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0$ is finite-dimensional.  Because the linear map given by $$0 \times \cdots \times 0 \times V_j \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0 \ni (0,\dots, 0,v,0,\dots, 0)\mapsto v \in V_j$$ is an isomorphism, we know that $\dim(0 \times \cdots \times 0 \times V_j \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0) = \dim(V_j)$.  Thus $V_j$ is finite dimensional, completing the proof. $\square$

Can you give me some advice on how to write this up so it sounds a bit more formal?

Comment: Seems formal to me.

Comment: You might use the canonical projection $\pi_j$ to simplify the notation but the proof is good enough.

Comment: @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez (After Googling) By the canonical projection map do you mean what my book calls the quotient map: $\pi: V\to V/ U: \pi(v) = v+U$?  If so, could you expand on how that function can be used to simplify the notation?  Or did you just mean the $T_j$ that levap defines in his answer?

Comment: neither. I mean $\pi_j :V_1\times V_2\times ... \times V_m\rightarrow V_j $ where $\pi_j(v_1,v_2,...,v_m)=v_j$ which is linear and epijective

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is good and is already quite formal. You can make it more explicit by defining a map $T_j \colon V_j \rightarrow V_1 \times \dots \times V_m$ given by
$$ T_j(v) = \underbrace{(0,\dots,v,\dots,0)}_{j\text{th place}} $$

and then arguing that this map is linear and injective. Hence, $T_j$ is an isomorphism from $V_j$ to $T_j(V_j)$. Since $T_j(V_j)$ is the image of a linear map, it is a subspace of $V_1 \times \dots \times V_m$ and since $V_1 \times \dots \times V_m$ is finite dimensional, so is $T_j(V_j)$ (being a subspace of a finite dimensional space).

Comment: That's a good idea.  Thanks!